# Focus matching input field with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying focus an input field into a div matching with an another input.

I have to skip reference input (first input value). Then, my code is:

```
$("#btnSearch").on('click',function() {
    input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    match = 0;
    for (i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
        if(input[i].value == $("#btnSearch > input").val()) {
            match = 1;
        }else if (match==1) {
            input[i].focus();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

But with this code, I focus next input (second input). It doesn't work. 
Any ideas to improve my code?

Comment: Can you upload your code on codepen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your focus `if` which checks `match` first like

Instead of

```
if(input[i].value == $("#btnSearch > input").val()) {
     match = 1;
}else if (match==1) {
    input[i].focus();
    break;
}
```

You should write

```
if(match==1) {
        input[i].focus();
        break; 
}else if (input[i].value == $("#btnSearch > input").val()) {
    match = 1;   
}
```

Exxplanation:

What your code doing is

1) Checks if condition for reference input, sets match to 1, as it is true,

2) Checks if condition for input, sets match to 1, as it is true

3) First if is false but match is true, so sets focus on next input

So we must check for match first, so that we get the focus on actual input